# How do you run a terminal command in a Gradle task?

Tags: maven, gradle, build.gradle

I have the following task:

```
task installMavenLocal(type: Upload) {
    description "Installs the artifacts to the local Maven repository."
    configuration = configurations['archives']
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository url: repositories.mavenLocal().url
        }
    }
}
```

When I run my Gradle command I do the following `gradle installMavenLocal -x:test:packageRelease`, is there a way I can add that command to my above task so that developers don't need to add the `-x:test:packageRelease` and it just runs when I do the task?

Answer (score 0):

You could use :

```
installMavenLocal.dependsOn.remove(tasks.getByPath(":test:packageRelease"))
```